# Javascript window.open() does not display new content in IE 8 unless refresh

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a .NET app to search for data that opens the search result in a popup windows on click. On the 1st click the search button, results are populated correctly in the new popup windows - let's name it ResultPopup. On the 2nd search button click, the results are not populated over ResultPopup window - unless there's a postback or fresh action to ResultPopup window.

All of this works fine on FireFox. Here's my aspx search click function (trigger onclick)

```
protected void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["RNum"] = RNumTxtBox.Text.Trim();
    Session["Location"] = LocationTxtBox.Text.Trim();
    Decimal dTemp;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(QNumTxtBox.Text) &&
        Decimal.TryParse(QNumTxtBox.Text, out dTemp))
    {
        Session["QNum"] = dTemp;
    }
    else
    {
        Session["QNum"] = 0;
    }

    Session["INum"] = INumTxtBox.Text.Trim();
    Session["PNum"] = PNumTxtBox.Text.Trim();
    Session["SValue"] = SRadBtnList.SelectedValue;

    // sPageName is a class variable - predefined URL
    // sTarWinName is a class variable - target window name for all search results
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenSearchMain", string.Format("javascript: popSearchResultWindow('{0}', '{1}');", sPageName, sTarWinName), true);       
}
```

Heres's my JavaScript function:

```
function popSearchResultWindow(pageName, tarWinName) {
    var sUrl = pageName;
    var oSearchResultWin = window.open(sUrl, tarWinName, 'location=1,resizable=1', false);

    //  oSearchResultWin.location.reload(true);
    //  using reload or refresh will give javascript: permission denied (after 4-5 click)
    oSearchResultWin.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be 2 reasons
1) your name has spaces, dash or other punctuations

or

2)ie8 does not support "name" as the 2nd value in the window.open()

your code should be

var oSearchResultWin = window.open(sUrl, '', 'location=1,resizable=1', false);

if you are to use the 2nd argument at all:
_blank
_media
_parent
_search
_self
_top

EDIT:
Have you tried doing this:

```
var oSearchResultWin = false; 

function popSearchResultWindow(pageName, tarWinName) { 
if(oSearchResultWin && !oSearchResultWin.closed){ 
    oSearchResultWin.location.href = sUrl; 
    oSearchResultWin.location.name = tarWinName; 
} 
else { 
    var sUrl = pageName; 
    oSearchResultWin = window.open(sUrl, tarWinName, 'location=1,resizable=1', false); 
} 
oSearchResultWin.focus(); 
}
```

Comment: 1) The target window name is correct - it loads correctly 1st time. The problem is that it won't display the new data on 2nd, 3rd, 4th, .. search click unless I manually refresh the page.                2) I need to display the data in one target windows only and i tried your suggestion but got error. var oReqSearchResultWin = window.open(sUrl, '_blank _media _parent _search _self _top', 'location=1,resizable=1', false);

Comment: I used '_search' as the target window name and it works but only locally. On server app pool it behaves the same - any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure why the _search does not work on the app pool. I think that you will need to uncomment the oSearchResultWin.location.reload(true);. the popup is getting cached by ie so when you load the url again it already sees that its been loaded. By forcing a reload it should refetch the page from the webserver.

Comment: reload() only works correctly for 4-5 different searches then comes the "Javascript: Permission Denied".

Comment: Have you tried doing this?

var oSearchResultWin = false;  
function popSearchResultWindow(pageName, tarWinName) {
    if(oSearchResultWin && !oSearchResultWin .closed){
       oSearchResultWin.location.href = sUrl;
       oSearchResultWin.location.name = tarWinName;
    }
    else {
    var sUrl = pageName;
    oSearchResultWin = window.open(sUrl, tarWinName, 'location=1,resizable=1', false);
    }
    oSearchResultWin.focus();
}

Comment: Are your urls from the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Matt.  I rework the code a bit since it still giving me the "Javascript: Permission Denied" error.

```
function popSearchResultWindow(pageName, tarWinName) {
var sUrl = pageName;
var oSearchResultWin = window.open(sUrl, tarWinName);
if (oSearchResultWin && !oSearchResultWin.closed) {
    try{
        oSearchResultWin.location.href = sUrl; oReqSearchResultWin.location.name = tarWinName;
    }catch (err){
        oSearchResultWin.location.reload(true);
    }
}
oSearchResultWin.focus();
}
```